# How can i Load local images to train model in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to build a CNN to differentiate between a car and a bicycle. However i saw the same example of a horse and a human in the Laurence's example here. But instead of loading the data from some library, i have downloaded close to 5000 images of cars and bicycle and segregated them as the folders suggested in the video. But how to load the local files to train my model? Am trying to use the below code. But it is giving me a file not found exception. [Here is the link to my colab am trying to do.](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1UEKnGsdq8nt16xXChOaFJaszrUEmyg8S?usp=sharing)

```
import os

# Directory with our training cycle pictures
train_cycle_dir = os.path.join('C:/Users/User/Desktop/Tensorflow/PrivateProject/Images/training/cycle')

# Directory with our training car pictures
train_car_dir = os.path.join('C:/Users/User/Desktop/Tensorflow/PrivateProject/Images/training/cars')

# Directory with our training cycle pictures
validation_cycle_dir = os.path.join('C:/Users/User/Desktop/Tensorflow/PrivateProject/Images/validation/cycle')

# Directory with our training car pictures
validation_car_dir = os.path.join('C:/Users/User/Desktop/Tensorflow/PrivateProject/Images/validation/cars')
```

Comment: please include all your code. These four lines won't give you a FileNotFoundException. And also, calling os.path.join with one argument is useless

Comment: Have added the link to the colab am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access files which are on your computer directly from colab. If you have enough space on your google drive, you can upload them to your google drive and mount it like [here](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb) or with the "Mount Drive" button on the files sidebar. There's also a button to upload files from your computer there. But if you upload them to colab, you have to do it again after 12 hours when the runtime resets. (you can read it [here](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html))